Find substring with same start and end characters
I've to detect a substring which starts and ends with the same characters.
import re
text = "/image/123.__W500__.png"
print(re.findall('__.*?__', text))

-> ['__W500__']

How can I get rid of the search pattern?
-> ['W500']
Thanks.

import re
text = "/image/123.__W500__.png"
print(re.findall('__(.*?)__', text))

->
['W500']


Using re is the right way to do this. However, if you wanted to do it without re then:
text = "/image/123.__W500__.png"
ps = "__"

try:
    i = text.index(ps)
    j = i + len(ps)
    k = text.index(ps, j)
    print(text[j:k])
except ValueError:
    print("Pattern not found")

Output:
W500

Note:
Using Python 3.12.2 on M2, this is significantly faster (~40%) than the accepted re solution. Here's the test rig:
import re
from timeit import timeit

text = "/image/123.__W500__.png"
ps = "__"


def pdiff(x, y):
    n = abs(x - y)
    d = (x + y) / 2
    return n / d * 100


def func1():
    try:
        i = text.index(ps)
        j = i + len(ps)
        k = text.index(ps, j)
        return text[j:k]
    except ValueError:
        pass


def func2():
    if v := re.findall(r"__(.*?)__", text):
        return v[0]


assert func1() == func2()

x = y = 0.0

for func in func1, func2:
    x, y = y, timeit(func)
    print(func.__name__, f"{y:.4f}s")

print(f"{pdiff(x, y):.2f}%")

Output:
func1 0.1953s
func2 0.2985s
41.81%


You cannot measure code efficiency with only such a simple input, and your code does not pick all occurrencies. Fix your code to match the functionality and then test it with text * 100. I'm sure you will see a different result.

As a reference, I have a result of 60μs per run using your approach and 26μs per run using re.findall on the string "/image/123.__W500__.png" * 100.

@ChrisFu Same platform?

Python 3.12.2 on I7.

Still doesn't pick ALL occurrences.

@ChrisFu Read the OP. It says "a substring" not "ALL substrings"

If the purpose were to find one substring, it would be very strange to make use of re.findall. But when it is, you are right that your approach is faster than using any of re method.
